# Returning object values in an object?

Tags: javascript

I want to access two parameters to a function and turn them into a single object to pass to another function. I know about `Object.values`, but I don't want to call `otherFn` with an array, I want an object. What's the best way to approach this?

```js
const exampleFn = (x, y) => {

  otherFn(?);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an object with the function's arguments:

```
const exampleFn = (x, y) => {
  otherFn({x,y});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the arguments from the first function.
Put them into an object.
Pass object to second function.

```
const exampleFn = (x, y) => {
  const args = {x: x, y: y}
  otherFn(args)
}
```